# card swipe, asp.net, parsing, autopostback

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, swipe

I can get the card to parse out but when i swipe the card it displays all the numbers and when i click tab or click anywhere thats when the actual parsed numbers show up. Is there a fix for it?

Comment: i have an <asp:textbox> and what i am trying to do is when i swipe a card( membership card).. i want it to display just a part of the card number... I got that part to work using substring. But when i initially swipe the card it show all the 219 characters and i have to press tab or click outside the textbox for it to execute the code. How do i get the textbox to not show all the 219 characters and just the 16 characters that i need without having to press anything.

Comment: You need to show your code for us to be able to help out with this.  Sounds like your event is firing on TextChanged.  Even with AutoPostBack set to true, that will only trigger when the TextBox loses "focus"

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using a magnetic card reader.  Treat the magnetic card reader as keyboard but instead of you pressing keys you are reading the data embedded in the card.

You have to create an event handler for the text box to parse the data as the card reader is spitting it out. Here are some sites to help you out:

1. Javascript's [onkeypress](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp) event
2. JQuery [keypress()](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) function

Comment: I have the code behind to parse the data but what i wanna do is not display the all the numbers when i swipe the card.. this is what i have so far                                                  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="check"  AutoPostBack="true" 
    onkeypress="myFunction()" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" ></asp:TextBox>

Comment: protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string initialValue = TextBox1.Text.ToString();
           
            if (initialValue.StartsWith("{"))
            {  
                string sixteenDigitID = initialValue.Substring(79, 16); //Substring(startIndex, Length)
                TextBox1.Text= sixteenDigitID;
               
            }
        }

Comment: AutoPostBack only happens when you submit the form.  You should do the parsing in the client using JQuery.  If you really insist in doing it in the server you should look into using the ASP.NET AJAX Controll Toolkit to automatically do the postback for you.